# PHP - like button with ip address

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, static-ip-address

My website has a like button that is similar to facebook like button. When user click it, the count increases. On clicking again, count decreases. Same as we click like and unlike in facebook. So only logged in users can hit like button

But the problem is no one is hitting the like button. I think it is due registering. My website is new. So visitors may not be interested in clicking like button after registering (even though i have included facebook login)

My question is can i use ip address for like button working. So visitors can click like button even without registering. I will write a php script that will capture ip address. So when clicked ip address is stored instead of username. Again clicking it will make it unlike.

I hope the idea is clear. Can i use this technique?? Because i heard ip address changes often.

this is my website [www.huzup.com](http://www.huzup.com) Its and online directory and search engine where users can submit their website, find similar sites, rate each site by clicking a like button as described above

Comment: Its very possible to do, but you are correct, alot of ISP issue dynamic public ip's to there clients, some even issue NAT'd ip to there clients. So there will be cases where a user has clicked like, comes back to the page a few days later and will be able to click like again. In other words your "likes" will be inaccurate.

Comment: IP addresses can change even during a single session, maybe try using cookies instead

Comment: @Rob thanks a lot. Will cookies never expire?? The only thing i am using this may temporarily. How is my site and its idea? Any idea it will become hit?? in future i will make it so that only registered users can like. I don't know why. no visitors :(

Comment: Cookies will be more reliable, but can be removed, or expire. So still not the perfect solution here. Why not just stick the Facebook "like", I see its on your page already. Users will not need to auth, and it will be unique.

Comment: @Rob but the websites must be sorted according to the likes count. Can i get the like count from facebook?

Comment: O sorry i misunderstood, you probably could, but it would be a mission. I think you going to need to use cookies then to see if they have click like. Or when they click the like button ask them for the email address or something (easy to get around it, but atleast its something)

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001973/tracking-unique-visitors-only

Comment: @Rob sorry i didn't get what you mean. Can i get the numbers of users who hit like button?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with Cookies if you want to keep a track of the browsers.

Comment: thanks a lot. Will cookies never expire?? The only thing i am using this may temporarily. How is my site and its idea? Any idea it will become hit?? in future i will make it so that only registered users can like. I don't know why. no visitors :(

Comment: You can set the period for cookies to expire. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

Comment: In order to make your answer feasible for this site, you better _explain_ your solution instead of just posting blind code.